# What is this line of code? Is it an inbuilt function or object?

Tags: javascript

`String(5);`

What is 'String()' here? Is it an inbuilt function? Is it an instance of the String object, named String, that (you don't need to create and) is inbuilt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is actually an inbuild function of javascript and it converts the value of an object to a string.

You can find it directly on MDN:
[String() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: 'Creates a new String object. It performs type conversion when called as a function, rather than as a constructor, which is usually more useful.' So I guess in my instance as I was passing it an argument it was a function, but otherwise it would've been a constructor?

Comment: @tonitone110 Yes :), exactly.

Comment: So just to confirm, `String` or `String()` is an instance/variable of some inbuilt object called String. This instance/variable is aptly named 'String'. Is there any way we can see the String constructor function or is that too complex?

Comment: I actually don't really know, sorry.